# Visual Studio Database Project Parameterise Database Name in Scripts

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, database-schema

I have two databases (a test and a live), which I have created in SSMS 2008 R2. I use a Visual Studio 2010 Database Project and a Schema Comparison to suck up the schema from the test environment and control changes etc; that's all working fine and I'm ready to publish the entire database out into the live location.

The problem I have is that although I was careful to give the test and live databases the same name, they reference tables in pre-existing test and live databases that *do not have the same name*. This means that a correct test Stored procedure might look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TestDatabase.dbo.Customers
```

but the *same* procedure, when published to the live environment, needs to use the different name of the existing live database:

```
SELECT * FROM LiveDatabase.dbo.Customers
```

When it comes to publishing from the Visual Studio Database Project to the live environment, I could do a find and replace to all scripts to substitute database name with another, but I am reluctant to make changes to the scripts directly before publication; doing this will also mean that the Visual Studio scripts will no longer match the test environment scripts, which will confuse things and force check-outs where no "real" sense changes have been made, not to mention slight irregularities in syntax causing references to be missed.

So my question is this - is there some other way to change all the references in the scripts in the database project (for instance, by using a parameterised database name) in a fairly clean way?

I can easily re-write the stored procedures if necessary, as a one off, but I cannot change the names of the pre-existing databases.

Comment: The ONLY way to parameterize object (database, table, column etc) names is to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: I see; thanks for the answer. I had hoped that something might be possible in a pre-deployment script or something. Ah well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you have already found the answer to this. If not, please try adding a database reference to the database project call it '`varDatabase`'. Make sure all your scripts are checked into `TFS` with this reference instead of hardocing the database name. You can call this reference using $ e.g., `[$(varDatabase)]`.
During publish, you can pass the value to this variable as one off thing.

Comment: Excepting the references to TFS, this is indeed the solution - I have created database references to the two `LiveDatabase` and `TestDatabase` and reference these in my two projects. It works like a charm. See this MSDN article for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193259(v=vs.100).aspx